# Displaying SpreadSheet (OpenXML) cell styling in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, openxml

I would like to display Excel SpreadSheet on the webpage. Seems like when I am using ADO.NET I can only access to data but is there some way so I can also know which rows/cols are formatted in special way like headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to use [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&DisplayLang=en)

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can render a range of cells, or a chart, as an image with custom number formats, fonts, colors, borders, charts, etc...

You can see some live ASP.NET samples (C# and VB) of this [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/imaging.aspx) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC